# Simple vertical align issue with div

Tags: html, css

My brain is fried so I need you guys help.

I am trying to do a vertical align in a div.

I have

html

```
<a href='#'>
  <div class="div">
     <div class="insideDiv">text here</div>
  </div>
</a>
```

My css

```
a {
   color: #006699;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 10pt;
   border-width: 0;
   position: relative
}

.div{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  top: -75px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  padding: 8px;
}

.insideDiv{
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 47px;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

It seems like `text here` can't be vertically align to middle but is horizontally align to center. Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically Align text in a Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: I think, having `div` in `a` give you error in w3c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) property doesn't apply to block-level elements, only elements in the inline formatting context and table-cells

You can add `display: table-cell;` to your `.insideDiv` class to vertically center its text:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/qTkAN/1/